# How to create extra Excel sheets showing data sorted differently

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel spreadsheet with around 10 columns and 100 rows...

Depending on context, I want to see the data in different orders, e.g.

- Scenario A

  - Sort spreadsheet by Column 1
- Scenario B

  - Sort spreadsheet by Column 3, 6, 2 (descending)
- Scenario C

  - Sort spreadsheet by Column 1, 2, 4, 3

etc...

It's driving me nuts keeping changing the sort order...

**Is there a way to create additional Sheets that each show the data from the first sheet, just sorted in different orders**

Then I could have sheets called e.g.

- Master Data
- Scenario A
- Scenario B
- Scenario C

Comment: Is the data dynamic? In other words, are you adding, removing, or changing the master data regularly?

Comment: Yes, the data is dynamic, changing regularly, and I was hoping that the views would update their content and sort order automatically, or at least with as few steps as possible.

Comment: It is frustrating, but Excel does not seem to support this functionality, at least not without writing a script.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can! It's hacky but easy to do:
 1. Open a ScenarioA sheet. Do a "formula copy" of the whole sheet. For example: 
Put "=MasterData!A1" in cell A1 of ScenarioA sheet and drag that across. 
 Now, you have a copy of the MasterData but that's not robust for moving around!
 2. Find/Replace: =MasterData! with =MasterData!$
 3. Find/Replace: =MasterData!$A with =MasterData!$A$ (do this for all columns)

Now, the references in the scenario sheet are fixed and if you sort, they will not re-evaluate to something else.

Comment: Doesn't step 2 break the process? If you search for `=MasterData!A` after you've already added the first `$` you won't find anything.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get good sleep and the coffee machine was busted today :) Will fix!

Answer (score 0):

You can use data connections. First, format your master data as a table by clicking anywhere inside the data and pressing ctrl+T. Then on each of your three sheets go to the Data Tab >> Get External Data Group >> Existing Connections >> Tables tab and select your table.

When you add or change your data you must refresh your connections by going to the Data Tab >> Connections group >> Refresh All.

Comment: Thanks. I've done the Ctrl+T bit, and created the table. When I got to Data Tab >> Get External Data Group >> Existing Connections, there is no Tables tab. When I click on 'Show:' dropdown, and choose 'Connections in this Workbook' it says '<No connections found>'. Any ideas, please?

Comment: @ClareMacrae From the Existing Connections dialog, click on Browse for More... then navigate to where your workbook is saved and select it. Then you can select the Master Data worksheet.